# Extending NDSolve beyond a singularity

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

The $\tan$ function satisfies the following IVP:

$$y'=1+y^2 ,\quad y(0)=0 $$

and has simple poles at the points $x=\pi/2+ \pi n$ for integer $n$.

When trying to get $\tan$ via numerical integration, the command

```
NDSolve[{y'[x]==y[x]^2+1,y[0]==0},y[x],{x,-10,10}]
```

gives a solution which is defined only for $x \in(- \pi/2,\pi/2)$. Is there a way to extend the solution beyond the poles $x= \pm \pi/2$? What about singularities in the general case?

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting question! A very different approach will be needed, since `InterpolatingFunction[]` assumes that whatever it's approximating is continuous (thus, pole-free) throughout its domain...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can treat the variable $y$ as an element $[y_1 \colon y_2]$ of the projective line.  In code, this means replacing `y[x]` by `y1[x]/y2[x]`. For an IVP $y' = f(x, y), \ y(x_0) = y_0$, we translate the initial condition as $y_1(x_0) = y_0, \ y_2(x_0) = 1$.  Since the substitution yields an equation in two variables $y_1$, $y_2$,
$$y_1'y_2-y_1y_2'=y_2^2\;f(x,\,y_1/y_2)\,,$$
we need another equation. So to get a unique solution, we impose the condition in code as

```
y1[x]^2 + y2[x]^2 == y0^2 + 1
```

Since this condition is satisfied initially, `NDSolve` will use it in conjunction with the ODE to determine `y1[x]` and `y2[x]` at each step.  We can use this condition as it is and solve the system as a [differential-algebraic equation (DAE)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html); or we can differentiate it and solve the system as an ODE.  The important difference is that the methods and precision available for DAEs are limited.

```
eqn = y'[x] == 1 + y[x]^2;
blowup = {y -> (y1[#]/y2[#] &)};

newfn = eqn /. blowup /. Equal -> Subtract // Together // Numerator;

newDAE = {newfn == 0, y1[x]^2 + y2[x]^2 == y0^2 + 1};
newODE = {newfn == 0, D[y1[x]^2 + y2[x]^2 == y0^2 + 1, x]};

Block[{x0 = 0, y0 = 0},
  sol = NDSolve[{newDAE, y1[x0] == y0, y2[x0] == 1}, {y1, y2}, {x, 0, 10}]
  ];

Block[{x0 = 0, y0 = 0},
  sol = NDSolve[{newODE, y1[x0] == y0, y2[x0] == 1}, {y1, y2}, {x, 0, 10}]
  ];
```

Both solutions yield the same plots:

```
Plot[y[x] /. blowup /. First@sol // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare by overlaying the graph of tangent, the exact solution in this example:

```
Plot[{y[x] /. blowup /. First@sol, Tan[x]} // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Update: Another view of what is happening.*

A standard model of the projective line $[y_1\colon y_2]$ is a unit-diameter circle tangent to an axis. The corresponding affine line $y$ is given by $y_2 = 1$.  Here we project the solution in terms of `{y1[x], y2[x]}` onto the desired solution `y[x]` (for `x` running from `0` to `10`).

> [image]
>   *The projection from the circle model of the projective line onto the affine line `y2 == 1`.  (The cylinder is the product of the interval `0 <= x <= 10` and the projective line or circle.)*
>
> ```
> cplot2 = ContourPlot3D[y1^2 + y2^2 == y2,
>    {x, 0, 10}, {y1, -1.05, 1.05}, {y2, -0.05, 1.05},
>    ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.3], Mesh -> None];
> base = Show[
>    ParametricPlot3D[
>     Evaluate[{x, ( y1[x] y2[x])/(y1[x]^2 + y2[x]^2), y2[x]^2/(
>        y1[x]^2 + y2[x]^2)} /. First@sol], {x, 0, 10}],
>    ParametricPlot3D[
>     Evaluate[{x, y[x] /. blowup, 1} /. First@sol], {x, 0, 10}, 
>     PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 3], Exclusions -> Cos[x] == 0],
>    (*cplot1,*)cplot2,
>    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}, {-0.1, 3.05}}, 
>    AxesLabel -> {x, y1, y2}];
> (* * * * *)
> Manipulate[
>  Show[
>   base,
>   Graphics3D[{
>     Gray,
>     Table[InfiniteLine[{{0, y, 1}, {10, y, 1}}], {y, -2, 2}],
>     Table[
>      InfiniteLine[{{x0, -1, 1}, {x0, 1, 1}}], {x0, 0, 10, Pi/2}],
>     Red, Thickness[Medium],
>     Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}],
>     InfiniteLine[{{x, 0, 0}, {x, y[x] /. blowup /. First@sol, 1}}],
>     PointSize[Large], 
>     Point[{{x, 0, 0}, {x, y[x], 1}, {x, ( y1[x] y2[x])/(
>          y1[x]^2 + y2[x]^2), y2[x]^2/(y1[x]^2 + y2[x]^2)}} /. 
>        blowup /. First@sol]
>     }]
>   ],
>  {x, 0, 10}
>  ]
> ```

Comment: Very instructive and elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the lovely method Michael. Although it has been years since the question was asked, I've been recently trying to extend this method to ODE systems and/or higher order ODEs, such as the Weierstrass equation $y''=6y^2-1/2g_2$. However, I couldn't do it by embedding $(y,y')$ in either $\mathbb{RP}^1 \times \mathbb{RP}^1$ nor $\mathbb{RP}^2$. Any tips on how to extend your method to such systems?

Comment: @user1337 I haven't come up with one.  $y'$ depends on $y$, so you can affect $y'$ only by the choice of how to projectivize $y$. And `NDSolve` complains of stiffness when it tries to integrate the solution across the point at infinity.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **WhenEvent[ ]** function, maybe it's not the perfect **(not very accurate)** solution but it works.

```
sol = With[{eps = 10^5}, 
First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 + 1, y[0] == 0, 
WhenEvent[{y[x] == eps, y[x] == -eps}, y[x] -> -y[x]]}, 
y, {x, -10, 10}]];

Plot[{y[x] /. sol, Tan[x]}, {x, -6, 6}, 
PlotLegends -> {"NDSolve", "Tan[x]"}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thin, {Thick, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
 sol2 = With[{eps = 10^5}, 
 First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 + x, y[0] == 1, 
 WhenEvent[{y[x] == eps, y[x] == -eps}, y[x] -> -Abs[y[x]]]}, 
 y, {x, -10, 10}]];
 sol3 = First@DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 + x, y[0] == 1}, y[x], x];

 Plot[{y[x] /. sol2, y[x] /. sol3}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"NDSolve", "DSolve"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thin, {Thick, Dashed}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image]