# How to solve this DE?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm pasting a code of a DE.I'm getting error. Plz suggest correction.

```
Clear[x];
r=1;
eqn=x'[t]-1-r*x[t]-(x^2)[t];
sol=NDSolve[{eqn,x[0]==0},x,{t,0,100}][[1]];

tTicks=Range[-24,24 30,24];
tGrid=Range[-60,24 30,6];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t],x'[t]}/.sol],{t,0,100},Frame->True,FrameTicks->{tTicks,Automatic},FrameTicksStyle->Directive[Red,Thick],GridLines->{tGrid,Automatic},GridLinesStyle->LightGray,FrameLabel->(Style[#,14,Bold]&/@{x,Overscript[x,"."]}),AspectRatio->1]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{t,x[t]/.sol}],{t,0,50},Frame->True,FrameTicks->{Range[0,50,12],Automatic},FrameTicksStyle->Directive[Red,Thick],GridLines->{tGrid,Automatic},GridLinesStyle->LightGray,FrameLabel->(Style[#,14,Bold]&/@{t,x}),AspectRatio->1]
```

---

I made the correction regarding the syntax error. But still no execution.

The following code,

```
Clear[x];
r=1;
eqn=x'[t]-1-r*x[t]-x[t]^2==0;sol=NDSolve[{eqn,x[0]==0},x,{t,0,100}][[1]];
tTicks=Range[-24,24 30,24];
tGrid=Range[-60,24 30,6];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t],x'[t]}/.sol],{t,0,100},Frame->True,FrameTicks->{tTicks,Automatic},FrameTicksStyle->Directive[Red,Thick],GridLines->{tGrid,Automatic},GridLinesStyle->LightGray,FrameLabel->(Style[#,14,Bold]&/@{x,Overscript[x,"."]}),AspectRatio->1]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{t,x[t]/.sol}],{t,0,50},Frame->True,FrameTicks->{Range[0,50,12],Automatic},FrameTicksStyle->Directive[Red,Thick],GridLines->{tGrid,Automatic},GridLinesStyle->LightGray,FrameLabel->(Style[#,14,Bold]&/@{t,x}),AspectRatio->1]
```

Giving me the errors

> NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function x appears with no arguments. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {-x[t]^2+(x^2)[t]==0,x[0]==0} is neither a list of
>   replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used
>   for replacing. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {-x[0.00204082]^2+(x^2)[0.00204082]==0,x[0]==0} is
>   neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so
>   cannot be used for replacing. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {-1.
>   x[0.00204082]^2+(x^2)[0.00204082]==0.,x[0.]==0.} is neither a list of
>   replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used
>   for replacing. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed
>   during this calculation. >>

Regards

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it in `NDSolve`? If it is, the rest of the info is extraneous. Is it in the `ParametricPlot`? Then perhaps remove all of the unnecessary formatting options which are most likely irrelevant. Also, please edit your post so that the code are in code blocks: clock the grey question mark on the far right of the toolbar when editing your post for help. Edit: the error that you get tells you exactly what the problem is. Replace `eqn` with `eqn==0` inside `NDSolve`. Secondly, you have some syntax errors: `(x^2)[t]` should be `x[t]^2`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91670/1871

Comment: You seem to have added a new problem to the question.  Please do not do that.  Instead ask a new question.  If you click on the "edited..." link in the middle to the left of your name/gravatar, you can "roll back" to the previous question.

Comment: Correct your equation  `eqn = x'[t] - 1 - r*x[t] - (x[t]^2) ` and solve it easily with DSolve  `dsol = DSolve[{eqn == 0, x[0] == 0}, x, t] ` . (In this case you can ignore error message)

Answer (score 4):

This is an initial attempt to improve your answer. First eliminate errors in the first three lines, and focus on a small `t` up to 1.2. Beyond that there is a singularity/stiff system. This is for the small `t` range!

```
     Clear[x];
     r = 1; 
    sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] - 1 - r*x[t] - x[t]^2 == 0, 
       x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1.2}]
    Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1.2}]
    ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], Derivative[1][x][t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1.2}]
```

[image]

First plot shown here.

Further to the singularity issue, one can explore the sensitivity of parameters for this specific differential equation using

```
Clear[x, r, s]; 
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] - s - r*x[t] == x[t]^2, 
   x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 5}, {r, s}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[x[r, 0.02][t] /. sol, {r, 0.1, 0.6, 0.02}]], {t, 
  0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[x[0.2, s][t] /. sol, {s, 0.01, 0.06, 0.01}]], {t, 
  0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The plot (s fixed at 0.02) show how quickly the curve shoots up even for smaller `r` values

[image]