# Plotting issue for nonlinear de

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

The following code with varying scaling parameter gives same plot. plz suggest correction.

```
Clear[x];

r=1;
eqn=x'[t]-1-r*x[t]-x[t]^2==0;
sol=x/.DSolve[{eqn,x[0]==0},x,t][[1,1]];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{sol[t],D[sol[t],t]}],{t,0,100}]

r=2;
eqn=x'[t]-1-r*x[t]-x[t]^2==0;
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{sol[t],D[sol[t],t]}],{t,0,100}]

r=-2;
eqn=x'[t]-1-r*x[t]-x[t]^2==0;
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{sol[t],D[sol[t],t]}],{t,0,100}]

r=0;
eqn=x'[t]-1-r*x[t]-x[t]^2==0;
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{sol[t],D[sol[t],t]}],{t,0,100}]
```

Regards,

Comment: The value of "r" has been changed several times.....maybe Clear[r] for each run?

Comment: If your version of Mathematica supports this form of Table then: Clear[x, r]; Table[eqn = x'[t]-1-r*x[t]-x[t]^2==0;  sol=x/.DSolve[{eqn, x[0]==0},x,t][[1,1]]; ParametricPlot[ Evaluate[{sol[t], D[sol[t], t]}], {t,0,100}], {r,{1,2,-2,0}}]

Comment: Because you set r before the DSolve, you have to run DSolve again every time you reset r. Alternatively, don't set r ever and instead replace r with the new value using /. for each ParametricPlot.

Answer (score 3):

[marsh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march) already has explained in a comment why the curves as generated by the code in the question look the same.  Here we offer some alternative approaches.

```
eqn = x'[t] - 1 - r*x[t] - x[t]^2 == 0;
sol = x /. DSolve[{eqn, x[0] == 0}, x, t][[1, 1]];
```

provides the solution for all `r` in the range `(-2, 2)`.  Plotting the four cases in the question on a single curve shows that they differ.  (Note the use of `Limit` to accommodate `r -> 2, -2`.)

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[Limit[{sol[t], D[sol[t], t]}, r -> i], {i, {1, 2, -2, 0}}]], 
    {t, 0, 100}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 35}}, PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

Gaps in two of the curves can be filled by using negative as well as positive values for `t`.

However, it also is straightforward to obtain `D[sol[t], t]` as a function of `sol[t]`.

```
FullSimplify[D[sol[t], t] /. Solve[x == sol[t], t][[1, 1]], C[1] ∈ Integers]
(* 1 + x (r + x) *)
```

In other words, the curves all are simple parabolas.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[%, {r, {1, 2, -2, 0}}]], {x, -5, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Here, there are no gaps, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I have deliberately confined this post to $t\in (0,1)$ to avoid stiffness issue (as discussed in related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96722/how-to-solve-this-de)).

```
f[x_, r_] := 1 + r x + x^2
Manipulate[
 With[{sol = 
    ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == f[x[t], s], x[0] == 0}, {x, x'}, {t, 
      0, 0.9}, {s}]},
  Column[{
    Show[Plot[f[x, r], {x, -3, 3}, Frame -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {0, 10}], 
     ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[r][t], x'[r][t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick, Dashed}, Frame -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {0, 10}], FrameLabel -> {"x(t)", "x'(t}"}],
    Show[StreamPlot[{1, f[x, r]}, {t, 0, 0.9}, {x, -3, 3}], 
     Plot[Evaluate[x[r][t] /. sol], {t, 0, 0.9}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}], FrameLabel -> {"t", "x(t}"}]
    }]], {r, -2, 2}]
```

Noting:

- x' v x can be plotted just by definition (see top plot)
- use of `ParametricNDSolve`

[image]