# NDSolve returns "stiffness" error

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following differential system:

```
s = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == -x2[t] - x3[t], x2'[t] == x1[t], 
     x3'[t] == 
      0.75*w1[t] + 0.5*w1[t]^4 + 5.5*w2[t] - 1.5*w2[t]^2 - 
       2.*w2[t]^3 + 0.5*w2[t]^4 + 
       w1[t]^2*(-3.5 - 2.*w2[t] + 1.*w2[t]^2) - 2.*x1[t] + 3.*x2[t] - 
       0.5*x2[t]^2 + 2.*x3[t], w1'[t] == 0.5 w2[t], 
     w2'[t] == -0.5 w1[t], w1[0] == 0.1, w2[0] == 0.1, x1[0] == 0.4, 
     x2[0] == - 0.4, x3[0] == -0.7} /. {b -> 0.5, a -> 0.5}, {x1, x2, 
    x3, w1, w2}, {t, 0, 800}, Method -> {"Shooting"}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
```

Mathematica returns a "stiffness" problem. How can I turn around this?

EDIT. The error message is:

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 3.4583389520816175`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

Comment: `x1`,`x2`,`x3` reach a singularity at `t==3.458`, so obviously `NDSolve[]` can't progress from there.

Comment: Are there any recommendations in these cases? @Feyre

Comment: Please include the error message in your question.

Comment: There's just no way to interpret the system beyond that point, the values all become infinite. There may be something wrong with your DE.

Comment: @MichaelE2 would you please explain how I choose the starting conditions in the shooting option.

Comment: Wait, you don't have a BVP, so the shooting method is an inappropriate choice. (I noticed only `Method -> {"Shooting"}`.) Feyre, is right, your solution reaches an asymptote at `t == 3.458`. That means the solution can be defined only up to that point. Usually that is the answer and one is satisfied with that.  In [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91690) I was able to projectivize the ODE and extend the solution past a singularity. You might be able to do it your case, but it's not clear whether that would be appropriate.

Comment: Method -> "StiffnessSwitching" helps, but doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I've tried that. I believe it is a singularity as Feyre said. @ivbc

Comment: Changing initial values may postpone singularity greatly.

Comment: Maybe you can talk a bit about the background of the equation set to make it more interesting?

Comment: It is a Rossler Prototype-4 equation setting parameteres a=0.5 and b=0.5. I've used this set of equations only to trial my functions because it is a well behaved chaotic dynamical system. @xzczd