# NDSolve error in 2-D heat equation

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions, finite-difference-method, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve the following PDE by Mathematica in 2-D case in the unit disk using polar cordinates,

[image]

where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\Gamma =\partial \Omega$ is the boundary of $\Omega$, $\partial_\nu$ is the normal derivative, and $\nu$ is the outer unit vector.

Thanks to [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) proposed by @xzczd I simplified the problem as follows:

```
eq = With[{u = u[t, r, z]}, D[u, t] == Laplacian[u, {r, z}, "Polar"]];
ic = u[0, r, z] == 1;
bc = With[{u = u[t, r, z]}, (eq[[1]] == eq[[2]] - D[u, r]) /. r -> 1];
tend = 1;
domain@r = {2 10^-6, 1};
domain@z = {0, 2 Pi};
points@r = points@z = 25;
difforder = 4;
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {r, z};
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[t, r, z], t, grid /@ {r, z}, difforder];
delbothside = #[[1 ;; -1]] &;
ode = delbothside /@ delbothside@ptoofunc@eq;
odeic = delbothside /@ delbothside@ptoofunc@ic;
odebc = MapAt[delbothside, ptoofunc@bc, {{1}, {2}}];`
```

When integrating the resulting ODEs with `NDSolve` :

```
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, 
 Outer[u, grid@r, grid@z], {t, 0, tend}];
```

It generates the following error

```
NDSolveValue::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables
 {u[1/500000,0][t],u[1/500000,\[Pi]/12][t],u[1/500000,\[Pi]/6][t],u[
 /500000,\[Pi]/4][t],u[1/500000,\[Pi]/3][t],u[1/500000,(5 \[Pi])/12
 [t],u[1/500000,\[Pi]/2][t],u[1/500000,(7 \[Pi])/12][t],u[1/500000,(2
 \[Pi])/3][t],u[1/500000,(3 \[Pi])/4][t],u[1/500000,(5 \[Pi])/6][t],u[
 /500000,(11 \[Pi])/12][t],u[1/500000,\[Pi]][t],u[1/500000,(13 \[Pi])/12
 [t],u[1/500000,(7 \[Pi])/6][t],<<22>>,u[500023/12000000,\[Pi]
 [t],u[500023/12000000,(13 \[Pi])/12][t],u[500023/12000000,(7 \[Pi])/6
 [t],u[500023/12000000,(5 \[Pi])/4][t],u[500023/12000000,(4 \[Pi])/3
 [t],u[500023/12000000,(17 \[Pi])/12][t],u[500023/12000000,(3 \[Pi])/2
 [t],u[500023/12000000,(19 \[Pi])/12][t],u[500023/12000000,(5 \[Pi])/3
 [t],u[500023/12000000,(7 \[Pi])/4][t],u[500023/12000000,(11 \[Pi])/6
 [t],u[500023/12000000,(23 \[Pi])/12][t],u[500023/12000000,2 \[Pi]
 [t],<<575>>}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined.
```

I think the problem is in the part when we delete some ODEs to make place for BCs equations. I lost many days to solve this, but still unsolved.

**Update:**

To be more precise, the equation to solve in polar cordinates $(r,\theta)$ is

$$u_t=\frac{d^2 u}{d r^2}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{d u}{d r}+\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d^2 u}{d \theta^2} \quad in \quad \Omega'=[0,1)\times [0,2 \pi)$$
$$u_t|_{r=1}=(\frac{d^2 u}{d \theta^2}-\frac{d u}{d r}) \Big|_{r=1}, \quad and \quad u|_{\theta=0}=u|_{\theta=2 \pi}=1, \quad (BC)$$
$$u(0,r,\theta)=1 \; in \; [0,1)\times [0,2 \pi), \quad u(0,1,\theta)=1 \; on \quad [0,2 \pi) \quad (IC).$$

Comment: Several issues I can spot at the moment: 1. What's the meaning of $\Delta_\Gamma$? Are you sure the b.c. is translated correctly? 2. Where's the b.c. at $r=0$? 3. Where's the b.c. in $z$ direction?

Comment: 1. Please explain what's Laplace-Beltrami operator. 2. You do need boundary condition for $r=0$ and in $z$ direction. Notice when analytically solve PDE in polar coordinate, though we don't use explicit b.c. for $r=0$, we always make use of implicit constraint such as "the solution is bounded in the whole domain", and you need to translate such implicit constraint to explicit boundary condition when implement FDM and its friends. Needless to say you also need b.c. for $z$, given it's the angle of the polar coordinate, the b.c. is _usually_ periodic b.c..

Comment: The obvious solution is `u[t,r,z]=1`. Therefore, we can put `u[t,0,z]==1` and add periodic boundary conditions `u[t,r,0]==u[t,r,2*Pi]`.

Comment: @Alex Reading the follow up comments of OP, the problem seems to be circularly symmetric. If so, a possible b.c. for $r=0$ is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\big|_{r=0}=0$. Deduction: `Expand[(r #1 &) /@ With[{u = u[r]}, D[u, t] == Laplacian[u, {r, theta}, "Polar"]]] /. 
 r -> 0(* 0 == Derivative[1][u][0] *)`.

Comment: @Alex, I think I get your idea, and it seems to be true following this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1794380/515871

Comment: Hello @xzczd and Alex. It have been a long time and my question still unaswered. I updated my post with the precise quation based on Alex coments. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @S.Cho See my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that OP still has difficulty in understanding why

1. Periodic b.c. should be added in $\theta$ direction.
2. Certain b.c. should be added at $r=0$.

If so, I suggest OP have a look at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192980/1871) first, which solves Laplace equation based on FDM from scratch i.e. without tools like `pdetoode`.

Anyway, the following is the fixed code.

```
eq = With[{u = u[t, r, z]}, r^2 D[u, t] == r^2 Laplacian[u, {r, z}, "Polar"] // Simplify];
ic = u[0, r, z] == 1;
bc = With[{u = u[t, r, z]}, (eq[[1]] == eq[[2]] - D[u, r]) /. r -> 1];
tend = 1;
domain@r = {0, 1};
domain@z = {0, 2 Pi};
points@r = points@z = 25;
difforder = 4;
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {r, z};
```

Notice we can impose periodic b.c. by setting 5th argument of `pdetoode`:

```
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[t, r, z], t, grid /@ {r, z}, difforder, {False, True}];
delbothside = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ode = delbothside@ptoofunc@eq;
odeic = ptoofunc@ic;
odebc = ptoofunc@bc;
```

At this point, we have `(points@r - 2) points@z + points@z == 600` equations at hand, while `points@r points@z == 625` unknown variables to be solved. Where can we find another `points@z == 25` equations? Given the problem is defined in polar coordinate, we know `u[0, …][t]` are the same:

```
bcorigin = Equal @@@ Partition[u[0, #][t] & /@ grid@z, 2, 1];
```

This gives us `points@z - 1` equations. Where can we find the final one? There're many possible ways, I'll simply utilize the idea mentioned [in this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20190624172011/http://homepages.see.leeds.ac.uk/%7Eamt6xw/Distance%20Learning/CFD5030/node10.html) i.e. approximating $\nabla^2 u$ at $r=0$ as

$$\nabla^2 u = \frac{4 \left( u_m - u_0 \right)}{\left( \Delta r \right)^2}$$

where $u_m$ is the mean value of $u$ along  $r = \Delta r$:

```
bcadditional = 
  With[{dr = grid@r // Differences // First}, 
   With[{um = u[dr, #][t] & /@ grid@z // Mean}, (4 (um - u[0, 0][t]))/dr^2 == 
     D[u[0, 0][t], t]]];

sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc, bcorigin, bcadditional}, 
   Outer[u, grid@r, grid@z], {t, 0, tend}];

solfunc = rebuild[sollst, grid /@ {r, z}]

Plot3D[solfunc[tend, r, z], {r, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The result is trivial as expected, but the solution above should work for more general cases.

Comment: Thank you. Yes your'e right. I'm confused about adding periodic bc condition because in the equation with Cartesian coordinates this bc don't arise. And since polar coordinates yield equivalent equation it should be same bc fixed in the beginning. I wish that I explained the problem well.  May be I need time to understand many steps.

Comment: @S.Cho You may understand the periodic b.c. in the following way: the property of polar coordinate should be relfected in the solving process. What property does it own? Periodicity i.e. $u(t, r, \theta)=u(t,r,\theta+2\pi),\frac{\partial u(t, r, \theta)}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial u(t, r, \theta+2\pi)}{\partial \theta},…$.

Comment: We have already discussed this at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190360/boundary-conditions-involving-time-derivative/190438#190438

Comment: @xzczd I can not find the definition of the function `rebuild[]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Nope, OP was trying to solve a 1+1D problem in Cartesian coordinate in that question, while this one is a 2+1D problem in polar coordinate. As to `rebuild`, it's included in the recent update of `pdetoode`/`pdetoae`.

Comment: @xzczd Can you give a link to the update?

Comment: @Alex It's just [there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) :) .

Comment: @xzczd Thank you! When executing the code, the system displays a message  `NDSolveValue::chknic: Structural analysis indicates that 601 initial conditions are needed to fix the state of the system. Currently only 575 initial conditions are specified. NDSolve may return one of a family of solutions.`

Comment: @Alex Oops, there should be no `delbothside@` in the definition of `odeic`, fixed. Thx for pointing out. (BTW this warning doesn't exist in _v9_, I believe it's added attempting to resolve the problem mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156153/1871) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154815/1871), but sadly the problem is still pending. )

Comment: @xzczd thank you, now the code works.

Comment: @xzczd what is the idea behind $\nabla^2 u = \frac{4 \left( u_m - u_0 \right)}{\left( \Delta r \right)^2}$? (the page you mentioned is not working).

Comment: @Migalobe  The page is still available in way back machine. (The images are broken, but still readable, I've added it to my answer. ) In short, this formula is a generalization of $$\begin{array}{r@{}l} \nabla^2 U & {}= \displaystyle\frac{u_1 + u_2 + u_3 + u_4 - 4u_0}{\left( \Delta r \right)^2} \\[4mm] &{}= \displaystyle 4 \left[ \frac{u_1 + u_2 + u_3 + u_4}{4} - u_0 \right] \bigg/ \left( \Delta r \right)^2 \end{array}$$ (The page doesn't contain a strict proof, but I think the explanation is plausible. )

Comment: @xzczd many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by iterations. Here, the function `u[t,r,z]` is restored by the value of the function `v[t,z]`, and the function `v[t,z]` by the value `Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 1, z]`. In this example, the solution converges quickly  to `u[t,r,z]=1` and `v[t,z]=1`(I changed `bc` at `r=r0=10^-6`).

```
U[0][t_, r_, z_] := 1;
V[0][t_, z_] := 1; n = 5; r0 = 10^-6;
Do[U[i] = 
   NDSolveValue[{-(D[u[t, r, z], {z, 2}]/r^2) - D[u[t, r, z], r]/r - 
       D[u[t, r, z], {r, 2}] + D[u[t, r, z], t] == 0, u[0, r, z] == 1,
      u[t, r, 0] == u[t, r, 2*Pi],u[t, r0, z] == 1, 
     u[t, 1, z] == V[i - 1][t, z]}, 
    u, {t, 0, 1}, {r, r0, 1}, {z, 0, 2*Pi}]; 
  V[i] = NDSolveValue[{-D[v[t, z], {z, 2}] + D[v[t, z], t] + 
       Derivative[0, 1, 0][U[i]][t, 1, z] == 0, v[0, z] == 1, 
     v[t, 0] == v[t, 2*Pi]}, v, {t, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2*Pi}];, {i, 1, 
   n}] 


Table[Plot3D[U[i][1, r, z], {r, r0, 1}, {z, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, n}]

Table[Plot3D[V[i][t, z], {t, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, n}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Nice idea but still not accurate enough. I think the use of `pdetoode` by xzczd should give better results. Is it necessary to add periodic BCs ? Because the equation in Cartesian coordinates don't contain this extra assumption and it is well-posed. Why we need to add this BCs ?

Comment: @S.Cho Show your solution in Cartesian coordinates using `pdetoode`.

Comment: It is difficult to solve the pde in Cartesian coordinates, because the Laplace-Beltrami and normal derivative are not easy to calculate. They are defined in the framework of differential geometry, in which case we use parametrisation and the simple case is to work with polar coordinates.

Comment: @S.Cho If the equation is solved in polar coordinates, then the solution on the `z` coordinate is, by definition, periodic.

Comment: @S.Cho See update, now the solution converges quickly to `u[t,r,z]=1` and `v[t,z]=1`.

Comment: Well, with all due respect, though `u[t, r0, z] == 1` leads to the correct result in this case, it's just an opportunistic choice, because genrally nobody knows the value at the origin in polar coordinate. One possible general treatment for $r=0$ can be found here: http://homepages.see.leeds.ac.uk/~amt6xw/Distance%20Learning/CFD5030/node10.html (Particularly the part around formula (1.6). )

Comment: @xzczd In this case, we know that the initial data `u[0,r,z]=1` is the exact solution `u[t,r,z]=1`. Therefore we can put `u[t,r0,z]=1`.

Comment: Yeah, but generally we don't know the exact solution.

Comment: @xzczd We always know the initial data, so we can use `u[t,r0,z]==u[0,r0,z]` if no other offers.

Comment: I don't think that's a good choice, the value at $r=0$ generally changes over time. The proper b.c. should be deduced from the truth "the solution is smooth at $r=0$". (Not sure if this is the only possible way though. )