# Using NDSolve on the Painlevé equations

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions, singularity

In an earlier question of mine, I was looking for a way to handle certain kinds of singularities (poles) when using `NDSolve`. [Michael E2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91690/), which relied on projective geometry was the most upvoted answer.

I have tried generalizing his method to systems of second order
$$\begin{align*} u'&=f(u,v,t), \\ v'&=g(u,v,t), \\ u(t_0)&=u_0, \\ v(t_0)&=v_0,\end{align*}$$
by considering the pair of dependent variables $(u,v)$ as an element of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, that is
$$\begin{align*}u=\frac{u_1}{u_2},  \\ v=\frac{v_1}{v_2}.\end{align*}$$
This transforms the system to
$$\begin{align*}u_1' u_2-u_1 u_2'&=u_2^2 f \left( \frac{u_1}{u_2}, \frac{v_1}{v_2},t \right), \\
v_1' v_2-v_1 v_2'&=v_2^2 g \left( \frac{u_1}{u_2},\frac{v_1}{v_2},t \right). \end{align*}$$
In order to handle the under-determined nature of these equations, we add the constraints 
$$\begin{align*}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \left( u_1^2+u_2^2 \right)&\equiv 2u_1 u_1'+2u_2 u_2'=0, \\ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \left( v_1^2+v_2^2 \right)&\equiv 2v_1 v_1'+2v_2 v_2'=0. \end{align*}$$

---

As a test, here is the code to solve the $\sec$-$\tan$ system
$$\begin{align*}u'&=uv \\ v'&=u^2, \\ u(0)&=1, \\ v(0)&=0. \end{align*}$$

```
sol = NDSolve[{u1'[t] u2[t] - u1[t] u2'[t] == 
u2[t]^2 *u1[t]/u2[t]*v1[t]/v2[t], 
v1'[t] v2[t] - v1[t] v2'[t] == v2[t]^2* u1[t]^2/u2[t]^2, 
u1[t] u1'[t] + u2[t] u2'[t] == 0, v1[t] v1'[t] + v2[t] v2'[t] == 0,
u1[0] == 1, u2[0] == 1, v1[0] == 0, v2[0] == 1}, {u1[t], u2[t], 
v1[t], v2[t]}, {t, -4, 4}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

This works like a charm, in the sense that the quotients $u_1/u_2$ and $v_1/v_2$ behave like $\sec$ and $\tan$.  However, when I tried handling more complex problems, such as the [first Painlevé equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painlev%C3%A9_transcendents#List_of_Painlev%C3%A9_equations)
$$\begin{align*}u'&=v, \\ v'&=6u^2+t,\end{align*}$$
`NDSolve` couldn't integrate beyond the poles (with the error: `NDSolve::ndsz`: At `t == -1.25774722466261350439119698118`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.). Here is my (failed) attempt at doing this:

```
sol = NDSolve[{u1'[t] u2[t] - u1[t] u2'[t] == u2[t]^2*v1[t]/v2[t], 
v1'[t] v2[t] - v1[t] v2'[t] == v2[t]^2*(6 u1[t]^2/u2[t]^2 + t), 
u1[t] u1'[t] + u2[t] u2'[t] == 0, v1[t] v1'[t] + v2[t] v2'[t] == 0,
u1[0] == 1, u2[0] == 1, v1[0] == 0, v2[0] == 1}, {u1[t], u2[t], 
v1[t], v2[t]}, {t, -4, 4}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

My question:

Is there any way to adapt Michael E2's method in order to produce a numerical integrator for the first Painlevé equation that can integrate beyond poles?

Thank you!

Comment: The solution is to integrate *around* the poles.  I wish there were a suboption to `NDSolve`'s RungeKutta such as `IntegrationContour` to manually specify how to reach the end point...

Comment: I think trying a different constraint may help.

Comment: One approach I have used when I was investigating the Painlevé equations was to construct the (nonlinear!) ODE for the associated tau functions, which are analytic. As I recall, the problem was that they also had considerable exponential behavior that made the approach usable only for moderately-sized arguments.