# How to solve second order nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, nonlinear, singularity

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] + (y[x])^2 == 1, y[0] == 2, y'[0] == 3}, y[x], {x, 0, 30}]
g = Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], y'[x], y''[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, 30}, PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

I'm trying to coding this equation $y''+ y^2 =1$ with initial value $y(0)= 2$, and $y'(0)= 3$ using `NDSolve`.
Anyone could tell me what is the problem above in the code? 
Thank you.

Comment: It does solve the system, but I get a message which says that there is a singularity at x = 3.95.

Comment: Also, by changing the initial condition to y'[0] == 0 gives a nice periodic solution. Is this what you want ?

Comment: I need it to give me a graph, but I tried old method I learned before, and it didn't work.

Comment: How to change the initial value for y ' [0]=3 to y ' [0]=0 when the given initial in the problem is this one "y ' [0]=3"

Comment: I am not saying that we should change it. I am just pointing out that with y'[0] = 3 we get stiffness issues, which goes away with y'[0] = 0. Understanding of the physics of the problem may explain this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91670/1871

Answer (score 5):

The desired solution can be obtained semi-analytically.

```
s = DSolveValue[y''[x] + (y[x])^2 == 1, y[x], x] /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
(* -(-1)^(2/3) 6^(1/3) 
   WeierstrassP[(-(1/6))^(1/3) (c1 + x), {2 (-1)^(2/3) 6^(1/3), c2}] *)
```

Next, determine the constants by applying the boundary conditions.

```
bc1 = s /. x -> 0;
bc2 = D[s, x] /. x -> 0;
sc = FindRoot[{bc1 == 2, bc2 == 3}, {c1, I}, {c2, 1}] // Chop
(* {c1 -> -0.523953 + 1.79242 I, c2 -> -10.3333} *)
```

and plot.

```
Plot[Chop[s /. sc], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

The solution is periodic in `x`.  In light of the singularities in the solution, it is not surprising that `NDSolve` failed for `x` near 4.

**Addendum**

The period can be increased by decreasing `y'[0]` and becomes infinite for `y'[0] == 0`.  A `WorkingPrecision` of at least `45` is needed in that case.

Answer (score 2):

May not be exactly what OP wants but still:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] + (y[x])^2 == 1, y[0] == 2, y'[0] == 0}, 
  y, {x, 0, 30}]

g = Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], y'[x], y''[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, 30}, 
  PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

Gives the graphs as required. With y'[0] == 3 as given by OP there seems to be a singularity/stiffness at x = 3.95

Answer (score 2):

just a supplement to @Lotus answer:

Using ParametricNDSolveValue

```
Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] + (y[x])^2 == 1, y[0] == 2,y'[0] == ys}, y, {x, 0, 30}, ys]
```

you could do some parameter studies varying `ys=y'[0]`

```
Show[{
Plot[Table[Y[p][x], {p, .1, 3. , .1}] , {x, 0, 25},PlotRange -> {-5, 5}] ,
Plot[ Y[0][x] , {x, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.01], Red}], 
Plot[ Y[3][x] , {x, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> { Green },PlotRange -> {-5, 5}]
}]
```

[image]

which show, that only `y'[0]==0` gives convergent solution!
(The green solution is  `y'[0]==3` OP asked for )

Comment: Increasing `WorkingPrecision` will give a different plot for `y'[0]==0`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks, trying `ParametricNDSolveValue[... , WorkingPrecision -> 50]`  `Plot[Y[3][x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Green}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5} ]` doesn't finish ...

Comment: Works fine for me with `NDSolveValue` and Mathematica 11.3.  Solution is flat at about `-1` for large `x`, which agrees with the symbolic solution.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks, MMA 11.0.1.  NDSolve gives the solution in the range 0<x<3.95