# Non-autonomous ODE use NDSolve, error: Step Size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system is suspected

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have seen  this error `NDSolve::ndsz` many times when I use `NDSolve` to get the solution of a non-autonomous ODE. I try but all failed. Thanks, Here is the code, very simple

```
 s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 0.3 y[t], 
       y'[t] == -0.1 x[t] - 0.01 y[t] + 0.2 y[t]^2 + 0.5 Cos[2 Pi t] + 4, 
       x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 50 Pi}]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 50 Pi},  PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Comment: ParametricPlot won't show the graph properly. I don't know this way is suitable,the following works: `ListPlot[Table[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 50 Pi}], 
 PlotStyle -> Red]`

Comment: `NDSolve` is very robust for initial value problem (IVP) of ODEs, if it fails on such problem, the equation system itself is probably wrong. Just check: `Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 1.53}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @Xminer Your code is not working properly, notice the domain of `s` is `{0., 1.53703}`.

Comment: It's pretty clear that once `y[t] > 0` and `y[t]^2 > 0.1 x[t] + 0.01 y[t]` that a singularity will develop in finite time. To me that doesn't mean the code is wrong.  But if there's some reason why the actual problem should not have a singularity, then, yes, the code is not set up right. Here's an easy way to plot the solution: `s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 0.3 y[t], y'[t] == -0.1 x[t] - 0.01 y[t] + 0.2 y[t]^2 + 0.5 Cos[2 Pi t] + 4, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 50 Pi}]; ListLinePlot[{x, y} /. First@s]`

Comment: Here's an IC without a singularity: `s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 0.3 y[t], 
   y'[t] == -0.1 x[t] - 0.01 y[t] + 0.2 y[t]^2 + 0.5 Cos[2 Pi t] + 4, 
   x[0] == 50, y[0] == -1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 50 Pi}]; Graphics[{Blue, 
  Thick, Line[
   Transpose[{x["ValuesOnGrid"], y["ValuesOnGrid"]} /. First@s]]}, 
 Frame -> True]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh, I guess you mean something like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91670/1871)? I somehow forget about it.

Comment: @xzczd Something like that. I just mean if $dy/dt \ge v(y) > 0$, then from $\int dy/v(y) \ge \int dt$, we have if $\Delta t = \int_a^\infty dy/v(y)$ is finite, then $y$ blows up in time less than $\Delta t$.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I seem to understand, Thank you So much