# NDSolve: evolutionary singularity in coupled differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve coupled differential equation where a function attains a value such that its derivative is infinite.

```
NDSolve[
  {(B[x] x - (2/3) ft x^(5/2)) D[A1[x], x] + x A1[x] D[B[x], x] + A1[x] B[x] == 0, 
  (B[x] x - (2/3) ft x^(5/2)) D[B[x], x] - B[x]^2/2 + (fk (x D[A1[x]^γ, x] + A1[x]^γ))/A1[x] + 1 == 0, 
  A1[1] == a0, B[1] == b0}, 
 {A1[x], B[x]}, {x, 0.001, 1}][[1]]
```

where `a0 = 1, b0 = 1, ft = 0.0001, fk = 0.001` for $\gamma > 1$. The solution reaches a singular point when `B[x] x - (2/3) ft x^(5/2) == 0`.

Can you help me on how to solve this singularity problem?

Comment: One of the singularities is obviously at `x == 0`.  For gamma equal to 3/2, another is around `x == 2`.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: Basically I am looking on how to bypass when B[x] x - (2/3) ft x^(5/2) == 0. Do you know any method/technique for this?

Comment: Normally, one doesn't, I think. However, I did it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198242/4999) , which refers to another answer where I used it.  Your problem looks harder, but maybe it's manageable.