# BEYOND Singularity with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, singularity

Here is the code I want to numerically integrate my  nonlinear ODE"

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == -1/(1 + y[x])^2, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}]
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 3}]
```

**NDSolve** surely fails since it passes through the singular at the point **x=2.532686648521246**.

I tried another method from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191044/numerical-continuation-methods-for-bypassing-a-singularity-when-integrating-an-o/198242#198242) to  bypassing a singularity:

```
odey = R''[y] + R[y] + 1/(1 + R[y])^2;
BCm = {R[0] == 1, R'[0] == 1};
projODE = {odey /. R -> (p[#]/q[#] &) // Together // Numerator, 
 D[p[y]^2 + q[y]^2, {y, 2}]} == 0 // Thread;

projICS = BCm /. {R[y0_] == r0_ :> {p[y0], q[y0]} == {Numerator[r0], Denominator[r0]}, 
R'[y0_] == 
  rp0_ :> ({D[p[y]/q[y], y] == rp0, D[p[y]^2 + q[y]^2, y] == 0} /. 
   y -> y0)};

 rules = {AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 20, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxSteps -> 20000};
 projSOL = NDSolve[{projODE, projICS}, {p, q}, {y, 0, 5}, rules, 
 Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic,
  "SimplifySystem" -> True}}]

 Plot[{p[y]/q[y] /. First@projSOL}, {y, 0, 4}, PlotLegends -> {p/q}]
```

but dosen't work.

My question is that, is there a convenient numerical continuation method to bypass the singularity so that **NDSolve** does not fail from range: **{x,0,5}** ?

Comment: I think a good place to start is to try to copy/paste the code Michael posted in the thread you refer to.  I tried and ran into a mess:  missing variables and lots of errors.  So I think first get his code working using the problem in that thread, then apply it to yours.  For example, variable "rat" is not defined anywhere in that thread but I think it can be 10^-10 for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a method that is adapted to stiff DE. E.g. "LinearlyImplicitEuler"

Here is your adapted example:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == -1/(1 + y[x])^2, y[0] == 1, 
   y'[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}, Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler"]
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Clever solution, fits well to the phaseplot in my answer!

Comment: The result of `Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]` looks very strange.

Comment: Could you also look at what happens if you try `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`?

Answer (score 2):

To long for a comment:

Perhaps `StreamPlot` gives  an idea of the possible solution?

```
StreamPlot[{yp, -y - 1/(1 + y)^2}, {y, -2, 1}, {yp, -3, 3},FrameLabel -> {y[x], y'[x]}]
```

[image]