# How to numerically integrate past singularities?

Tags: differential-equations, singularity, implicit

Is there any way to numerically integrate a differential equation where you know there are singularities? Can one "skip" over the singularity by using some type of implicit solver? Can one integrate in towards the singularity from both sides? etc. For example:

Let

`DD = F'[t] - F[t]^2 + 2 F[t] - 2 == 0`

This is a Riccati Differential Equation and this has the analytic solution

`gg = DSolve[{DD, F[0] == 0}, F[t], t]`

`{{F[t] -> 1 - Tan[1/4 (\[Pi] - 4 t)]}}`

which has singularities at `t=3*\[Pi]/4 + 2 n \[Pi]`.

However if I attempt to numerically integrate this DE:
`s = NDSolve[{DD, F[0] == 0}, F, {t, 0, 3}]`

The solver cannot find any way to deal with the singularity. Are there implicit solvers which can deal with such singularities?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191044/numerical-continuation-methods-for-bypassing-a-singularity-when-integrating-an-o/198242#198242,
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91670/extending-ndsolve-beyond-a-singularity/91690#91690

Answer (score 2):

**Introduction**

Here is a different approach than given in [Extending NDSolve beyond a singularity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91670/extending-ndsolve-beyond-a-singularity) or [Numerical continuation methods for bypassing a singularity when integrating an ODE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191044/numerical-continuation-methods-for-bypassing-a-singularity-when-integrating-an-o).  It could be an answer to [Extending NDSolve beyond a singularity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91670/extending-ndsolve-beyond-a-singularity), in which the solution is also periodic, I suppose, but I also wanted to address a problem with `"LinearlyImplicitEuler"`, a very easy approach given by Ulrich Neumann. My remarks on that turned out to be much too long for a comment, so I thought, if put them in an answer, I may as well answer the OP's question at the same time. Depending on the use-case, the ease of `"LinearlyImplicitEuler"` may outweigh the problems.

**Mathematically:**

1. The system is autonomous, so all solutions defined in a small enough open interval about some number $t=t_0$ are equivalent via a phase shift $F_1(t) = F_2(t-c_{12})$.
2. However, when we wish to extend the domain to disjoint union of open intervals, then different solutions are not necessarily equivalent via phase shifts. The solution over each interval may be independently shifted, provided the interval is small enough. In the OP's case the largest open interval over which a solution is feasible has length $\pi$, which is known only because the ODE has a simple, exact solution. So over an interval of length $p=\pi$, there is a unique solution, which satisfies the boundary conditions that it blows up at the endpoints.  This (finite) maximal length $p$ may be used to extend a solution over the open interval to a periodic solution, defined for at $t$ except at the endpoints of the open interval and its translates by $np$, $n$ any integer.
3. OTOH, if $F(t)$ is a solution, then so is $F(t-c)$, for any $c$, albeit over a translated domain that might overlap the domain of $F$. If, as in the OP's case, the solution $F$ can be extended to a periodic solution of (finite) period $p$, initially defined over a domain $(a, a+p)$, then there is a unique solution with this domain.  Equivalently, an initial condition defines a domain, the largest over which the solution is defined, and this solution can be extended uniquely to a periodic solution.
4. It can also happen that we construct a solution in which the function value over adjacent disjoint open intervals are related by a translation $F(t)=F(t-c)$, for $t$,$t-c$ each in the respective intervals. It must be the case that $|c|\le p$ or there would be a gap between the intervals. If $c\ne\pm p$, then the intervals cannot have the same length, and the function won't be periodic. Such a solution is usually disparaged. This Frankenstein monster of ill-fitting pieces is usually kept hidden from undergraduates and other civilized people.

**Numerically**:

1. `InterpolatingFunction` cannot handle asymptotes, so `NDSolve[]` does not try to handle your sort of problem; however, sometimes the step/error control in `NDSolve` misses a singularity. For instance, `Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler"` essentially uses a fixed step size based on some sort of error estimate for the initial step size. So `NDSolve[{y'[t] - y[t] == 0, y[0] == 1/2}, y, {t, 0, 10},  Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler"]` and `NDSolve[{y'[t] - y[t]^2 == 0, y[0] == 1/2}, y, {t, 0, 10},  Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler"]` use the same step size even though the solution to the first is an analytic function and the second has an asymptote at `t == 2`.
2. In, the neighborhood of an asymptote, if the step size does not become arbitrarily small, then the error of a polynomial interpolant will be arbitrarily large. This may not be important in every use-case if one is interested mainly in the solution for values of `t` away from the asymptotes.
3. When the solution steps across the singularity, the error is theoretically arbitrary; in fact, it is usually small but significant. For `NDSolve[{f'[t] - f[t]^2 + 2 f[t] - 2 == 0, f[0] == 0}, f, {t, 0, 16}, Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler"]`, the error compared to the exact solution exceeds `0.0001`after crossing the third asymptote . For instance the value of the numerical solution at `t == 3 Pi` is `-0.000239399`, whereas the value of the exact solution is `0`. Or examining the error as a phase shift (error in $c$ under the mathematical remarks above), the numerical solution is zero at `t == 9.424898` instead at `3 Pi`, a phase error of `0.000119687`. Adjusting the phase shift $c$ at each singularity reduces the error by several orders of magnitude, but it's unclear how to do this easily without know the exact solution.

**Solution**

***First,***
If the time it takes `f[t]` do change from `-Infinity` to `Infinity` is finite, the solution will be periodic. We may compute the period thus:
$$p = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {df \over f'(t)} \,.$$
The time to go from $-\infty$ to an initial condition $f(t_0)=f_0$ is given by the following:
$$t_o = \int_{-\infty}^{f_0} {df \over f'(t)} \,.$$

Here is a numerical calculation of the period and the time to the IC ("offset"):

```
dd = f'[t] - f[t]^2 + 2 f[t] - 2 == 0;
nperiod = 
 NIntegrate[
  1/f'[t] /. First@Solve[dd, f'[t]], {f[t], -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 32, PrecisionGoal -> 16]
noffset = 
 NIntegrate[1/f'[t] /. First@Solve[dd, f'[t]], {f[t], -Infinity, 0}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 32, PrecisionGoal -> 16]
N[Pi, 32]
```

> ```
> (* Numerical:                            Exact:
>    3.1415926535897932384626433833040   = Pi
>    0.78539816339744830961566084581988  = Pi/4
>    3.1415926535897932384626433832795
> *)
> ```

The exact values may be computed with `Integrate[]`, if possible as it is in the OP's example.

***Second,***
we use the period and offset to create a periodic solution and a high-precision for the sake of evaluating the method. Both give a `NDSolve::ndsz` warning, but as this is expected, it can be ignored.  `NDSolveValue[]` allows for (almost) any expression to be returned, so we can bake the periodicity right into the solution:

```
gensol // ClearAll; (* machine precision solution *)
gensol[t_] = 
 NDSolveValue[{dd, f[0] == 0}, 
  f[Mod[t, nperiod, -noffset]], {t, -noffset, -noffset + nperiod}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> All];

gensol32 // ClearAll; (* high precision solution *)
gensol32[t_] = 
  NDSolveValue[{dd, f[0] == 0}, 
   f[Mod[t, Pi, -Pi/4]], {t, -Pi/4, -Pi/4 + Pi}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 32, InterpolationOrder -> All];

dsol // ClearAll; (* exact solution *)
dsol[t_] = f[t] /. First@DSolve[{dd, f[0] == 0}, f[t], t]
(*  1 - Tan[1/4 (\[Pi] - 4 t)]  *)
```

Error plot:

```
Plot[
 {gensol[t], gensol32[t]}/dsol[t] - 1 // RealExponent // Evaluate,
 {t, -5, 5},
 GridLines -> {None, {-$MachinePrecision/2, -16}},
 WorkingPrecision -> 32,
 PlotLabel -> HoldForm[Log10["Rel. Err."]],
 PlotLegends -> 
  HoldForm /@ {WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 32}]
```

[image]

The upward spikes occur at the asymptotes where a rise in error is inevitable in polynomial interpolation.  The downward spikes are probably where the numerical solutions cross the exact solution.  The horizontal grid lines indicate the default `PrecisionGoal` for machine and 32-digit working precision. The internal estimate of the accuracy by `NDSolve` is based on the solution and system, not on the exact solution. We can see that the estimate is off by a couple orders of magnitude throughout most of the domain.

**Memory usage.**
Another point: `Head[gensol[t]]["Grid"] // Length` shows this took `1726` steps. The `"LinearlyImplicitEuler"` method over the same interval takes `210831` steps.

Answer (score 1):

Try  `Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler"`

```
solF = NDSolveValue[{F'[t] - F[t]^2 + 2 F[t] - 2 == 0, F[0] == 0},F, {t, 0, 3}, Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler"]

Plot[ solF [t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image]