# Step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages, singularity

```
η = 0.125; 
rg1s = Derivative[1][u1][t] - u1[t]*u3[t] - 3*u1[t]*u4[t] + u2[t]*u3[t] + 3*u2[t]*u4[t] + 2*(1 + 2*η)*u1[t]^2 == 0; 
rg2s = Derivative[1][u2][t] - u2[t]*u3[t] - 3*u2[t]*u4[t] + u1[t]*u3[t] + 3*u1[t]*u4[t] + 2*(1 + 2*η)*u2[t]^2 == 0; 
rg3t = Derivative[1][u3][t] - 0.5*((u1[t] - u2[t])^2 + u3[t]^2 - 3*u4[t]^2 + 6*u3[t]*u4[t]) == 0; 
rg4t = Derivative[1][u4][t] - 0.5*((u1[t] - u2[t])^2 + u3[t]^2 + 5*u4[t]^2 - 2*u3[t]*u4[t]) == 0; 
sol = NDSolve[{rg1s, rg2s, rg3t, rg4t, u1[0] == -0.6*0.2, u2[0] == -0.6*0.2, u3[0] == 0.6*0.2, u4[0] == 0.2}, {u1, u2, u3, u4}, {t, 1, 10}]
```

I am trying to solve four coupled nonlinear differential equations.
But, everytime I am getting

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 2.0833315360868916`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

I have tried all the possible ways to solve such kind of problem with similar kind of problems available in stack.
I want to get the value of g1,g2,g3 and g4 for large  value of t i.e. 1 to 100 but I am getting only for small value of t?
Could you please suggest me some way to sort out the issue?

Thank you

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Have you looked at the solution it computed? You probably have a singularity (perhaps a vertical asymptote). It is a feature of your IVP, not an error.

Comment: The plot doesn't have vertical asymptote but u1 and u2 being symmetric has the same solution.

Comment: `u3` and `u4` appear to have vertical asymptotes when I run your code.

Comment: {ListLinePlot[
 Flatten[Table[
   Evaluate[{u1[t], u2[t], u3[t], u4[t]} /. sol], {t, 1, 2}], 1], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "u1u2u3u4"}]} is my code for the plot which doesn't give vertical asymptote?Could you please share your code?

Comment: Your are right ,Plot[Evaluate[{u1[t], u2[t], u3[t], u4[t]} /. sol], {t, 1, 2}]  gives vertical asymptote.

Comment: Thank you Michael E2 for your response. Could you please let me know if   there is anyway to solve such problem keeping the same initial value conditions?

Comment: If the solution is correct (I assume it is, even with the asymptotes, which are an ordinary feature of functions), then how can you expect a different solution? I don't if [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91670/extending-ndsolve-beyond-a-singularity) is helpful....