# How to handle this singularity？NDSolveValue::ndsz: At s == 399, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, singularity

```
m11 = 1/(500 - s);
m22 = -m11;
m12 = I*1/(400 - s);
m21 = -m12; Vi=0; si=1; sf=3000;
Gammaad = Abs[m11]/Abs[m12];
{Aosol1, Aesol1} = 
   NDSolveValue[{I*Ao'[s] - (m11)*Ao[s] - (m12)*Ae[s] == 0, 
     I*Ae'[s] - (m21)*Ao[s] - (m22)*Ae[s] == 0, Ao[si] == Vi, 
     Ae[si] == Sqrt[1 - Vi^2]}, {Ao, Ae}, {s, si, 
     sf}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This error is reported as NDSolveValue::ndsz: At s == 399, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. A singularity occurred at s=400 for m12, how should I handle it?

Comment: Have you tried searching this site for the error you received? There are many questions on stiff systems

Comment: Please update your thread to include  values of Vi, si and sf

Comment: I have no problem up to `s == 399.99999999618143`, which is only a small step from `s == 400`. If you want to integrate past `s == 400`, you should explain more particularly how you want it done. It's not generally admitted in classical approaches. [This simple approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91670/extending-ndsolve-beyond-a-singularity/91690#91690) is probably difficult here, since the system here is higher dimensional, nonautonomous, and one of the singularities is in the s-domain.

Comment: I try add "Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1}}", it can solve this problem, but when the expression for m11 becomes very complex, this method calculates very slowly and even don't work. Is there any way to simplify the complex expression.

Comment: FWIW, `DSolve` will solve the system exactly.

Answer (score 2):

One cannot integrate the equation over s=400 because the derivative has a pole there

```
I*Ao'[s] - 1/(500-s))*Ao[s] - I/(400-s)*Ae[s] == 0
```

But the equation is solvable without the initial values in terms of Hypergeometric functions. Since the equations are linear, its easy to fit the two constants C[1], C[2] such that the initial values are met.